# Problemas ao enviar varias linhas em um formulário

Tags: php

```
$lista = $_POST['lista'];
echo substr("$lista", 0, 28);
?>

<form action="" method="POST"> 
<textarea cols=60 rows="10" name="lista" maxlength="500" wrap="hard" placeholder="coragem, você consegue ! "></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="Envia" value="Enviar"> 
<input type="reset" name="Apaga" value="Apagar">
```

Esta é a segunda vez que tento criar e estão fechando por falta de detalhes, peço ajuda por favor, um direcionamento, pois sinceramente não sei o que posso mudar para que fique mais claro...

Sei que está bem crú, mas é basicamente isso, vou colocar uma lista de números separada por linha e preciso que cada linha tenha uma limitação de caracteres.

Meu problema é: **Quando colo minha lista nela, apenas a 1º linha é trabalhada no PHP.**

O número de linhas vai variar, preciso que cada linha da lista seja formatada igualmente, que tenha os mesmos números de caracteres.

**Exemplo:**
Ao inserir a seguinte lista de números no *textarea*, preciso que retorne cada linha executando o comando `substr("$lista", 0, 5)` ou seja, cada linha seja limitada apenas a 5 caracteres.

```
11111111111111111111111111111
22222222222222222222222222222
33333333333333333333333333332
44444444444444444444444444444
```

No caso retornaria:

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

Atualmente, ao inserir a minha lista de números, apenas a 1º linha é executada, ou seja, retorna apenas:

```
11111
```

Ignorando todas as outras linhas...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, acredito que tenha entendido. Espero que possa te ajudar.

```
<?php
$lista = nl2br($_POST['lista']);
$dados = explode("\n",$lista);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    echo substr($linha, 0, 5)."<br>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: É exatamente isso mesmo!! Muito obrigado, não entendi os negativos, mas enfim, nem sei como agradecer por isso, tirou um grande peso das minhas costas haha!! Muito obrigado Junior.